# What are all the ways to update a control from a new class in form1?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have in form1 a listBox or listView or textBox and i want to update them in live.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test
{
    class Class1
    {
        string[] items = { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4" };

        public Class1()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
            {
                // Here update add the items to the control in form1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say i want to update the listView in form1.
But i don't want to wait untill all items will be added to the listView and then see the items i want that each single item will add and will be show in the listView. Like in live real time. So i need to use either backgroundworker or maybe invoke and i also need somehow to make the control in form1 to be accessable in this class.

There might be some ways to do it.
I know you can make in the new class an instance of form1 and in form1 to make the control/s to be public instead private. But if i want to make it without changing the control/s in form1 to public and without making new instance of form1 in the new class is it possible ?

I could also create another class that all he will do is to communicate using global vars between the new class and form1.

What are all the ways to do it and how can you do it ? I think this question might be helping for everyone.

Update

For a start i tried to do this:

```
public static void doStuff(object objtoadd)
            {
                foreach (Form1 frm in Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>())
                {
                    frm.Invoke(() => frm.addItemToListBox(objtoadd));
                }
            }
```

The error is on: () => frm.addItemToListBox(objtoadd)

Error   1   Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Each control is different.  You are better off relying less on gui controls and work with the data instead.  It's the reference to the data that you would pass into your class.  Use events to have everything talk to each other.  Don't worry about a BackgroundWorker until you get this all working.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and suggest you aren't ready yet to work with threads.  You are missing a `new Action` in your Invoke call.

Answer (score 0):

This question is too broad to give a meaningful answer. Asking for all the ways to do something is not specific enough. That being said, one possible idea is to create a `DataProvider` class that fetches the data, and provides events when new data is received. Then other classes such as user controls would register for those events. E.g.

```
public class DataProvider {

    public event EventHandler DataReceived;
    public int PollingFrequencyMillis = 5000;

    public DataProvider() {
    }

    public void StartDataPolling() {
        Thread t = new Thread((o) => {
            var dp = (DataProvider) o;
            String[] items = null; // fetch the data whatever your source is
            if (dp.DataReceived != null && items != null && items.Length > 0) {
                dp.DataReceived(dp, new DataEventArgs(items));
            }
            Thread.Sleep(dp.PollingFrequencyMillis);
        });
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start(this);
    }
}

public class DataEventArgs : EventArgs {
    public String[] Data { get; private set; }
    public DataEventArgs(String[] data) {
        Data = data;
    }
}

public class YourForm : Form {
    DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider();
    TextBox tb = new TextBox { Multiline = true, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
    public YourForm() {
        dataProvider.DataReceived += dataProvider_DataReceived;
        dataProvider.StartDataPolling();
        Controls.Add(tb);
    }

    void dataProvider_DataReceived(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        DataEventArgs e2 = (DataEventArgs) e;
        RefreshTextBox(e2);
    }

    void RefreshTextBox(Object o) {
        if (InvokeRequired) {
            BeginInvoke(new Action<Object>((o2) => {
                RefreshTextBox(o2);
            }), o);
            return;
        }
        DataEventArgs e = (DataEventArgs) o;
        tb.AppendText(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, e.Data));
    }
}
```

For the `DataProvider` class, you could enhance it to provide a flag to stop the polling, adjust the frequency of polling, and possibly cache a certain amount of historical data so if another control registers itself for events, it will be sent some of the recently polled data.